# How to run maven plugin before dependency check

Tags: java, maven, flex-mojos

I want to run maven-install-plugin before dependency check. How can I do that?
The plugin configuration:

```
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-library</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>my.assets</groupId>
                <artifactId>myAsset</artifactId>
                <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>swc</packaging>
                <file>libs/asset.swc</file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

Comment: Best is to use a repository manager upload the artifacts there and afterwards use the artifacts as usual dependencies. Makes life easier.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do it in the "clean" phase.

Upside: always runs before everything else

Downside: Have to run "clean" (mvn clean compile, mvn clean install etc)

Comment: Sathesh you need to trigger Clean only. If you click "Clean and Build" it will not work. This works for me in Netbeans if I right-click the project and click "Clean"

Comment: Is there a way to do this without have to run ```clean``` and ```install``` independently of each other?

Comment: You can call clean in a Jenkins pre step.