# Including classes and jars from a local war file with maven

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a War file that has dependencies and class files that I need in it that I am trying to include in my project with Maven. Inside the War file, there is a WEB-INF that contains those libs and classes. I have tried everything that I know to try to get this going, but my knowledge of Maven is limited.

- I have tried simply listing the War as a dependency and following the process described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to install the third-party library, but when I do that Maven says it can't find my packages that I need when I try to install.
- I have tried overlaying the War as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) with no luck.
- I have tried [maven-warpath-plugin](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/) but didn't really have any luck either.

Should any of these tools solve my problem? Is how I am trying to solve the problem possible in this way? Or am I completely off base?

Here are the important parts of my pom.xml from using the maven-warpath-plugin:

```
<build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.appfuse</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-warpath-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>data-local</id>
        <name>data</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/o</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.local.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyLocalDep</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.1</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.local.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyLocalDep</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.1</version>
        <type>warpath</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The maven-warpath-plugin should be a good start. What did you try? Do you have an example pom.xml which does not work using this plugin?

Comment: I added the pom, sorry.

Comment: A war file can't be use a dependency to be on the classpath only jar's. The war project might need to create a separate jar with the appropriate classes (see [maven-war-plguin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) archiveClasses, attachClasses configuration...those created jar's you could use..

Comment: Is this not [overlaying the war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) does? It talks about how you should be able to have a project depend on another war artifact, unless I am completely off base.

Comment: Try to use not `pluginManagement`, but `plugins` as surrounding section (remove the `pluginManagement` tags). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the war in a separate clean step first and add the unpacked jars as system dependency in the main step.

Idea is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120395/503025